# Handle fragment back navigation and bottom navigation view selected item

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, fragment-backstack

I have implemented a bottomNavigationView which each option has its entry fragment and some has more navigation under the same option.

Somehow like this:

A->A1

B->B1

C->C1->C2

D->D1

E->E1->E2

Where A,B,C,D & E are the options (MenuItem) for the bottom navigation view and A1,B1,C1,D1,E1 are the entry fragments for those options repectivly

The the desired navigation is that the entry AND exit point of the app will always be option A (entry fragment A1). So if the user navigates to another option as long as is in the entry fragment for that option, the behaivor for any back navigation should be to go to option A.

The problem I have is that the bottomNavigationView is always present as a requirement so the user could navigate to any option at any time.

For exemple if the user navigates to option E then in E1 takes an action that navigates to E2 an then navigates to option B if the user press the back button the app should go to option A because is in the entry fragment B1.
Also if the user navigates to option A using the bottom navigation view an then press the back button, as we are in the exit point we should be finishing the app.

In the OnNavigationItemSelectedListener I replace the current fragment for the entry fragment for the selected option using `beginTransaction.replace` for any options other than option A I add the `addToBackStack(null)` but this alone does not matches the desired navigation since if the user press the back button, insted of navigate to option A it navigates to the previous selected option. A have also tried to pop the back satck before replacing the fragment using `popBackStack(BACK_STACK_HOME_TAG, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)` and replacea adding `addToBackStack(BACK_STACK_HOME_TAG)` but somehow when selected a second option instead of showing the entry fragment for the selected option it shows the Fragment A1

```
navBar.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener {
    when(it.itemId) {
        R.id.optionA -> {

            // Removes all entries in the backstack if any
            if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 0) {
                supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(
                    null,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE
                )

                return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }

            // Replaces/add the entry fragment
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragmentHost, FragmentA1())
                    .commit()
            return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }

        R.id.optionB -> {
            // Removes all entries in the backstack up to BACK_STACK_HOME_TAG
            supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(
                BACK_STACK_HOME_TAG,
                FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE
            )

            // Replace the fragment with the entry FragmentB1
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragmentHost, FragmentB1())
                    .addToBackStack(BACK_STACK_HOME_TAG)
                    .commit()

            return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }

        R.id.optionC -> {
            // Removes all entries in the backstack up to BACK_STACK_HOME_TAG
            supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(
                BACK_STACK_HOME_TAG,
                FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE
            )

            // Replace the fragment with the entry FragmentC1
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragmentHost, FragmentC1())
                    .addToBackStack(BACK_STACK_HOME_TAG)
                    .commit()

            return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }

        ...

        return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener false
    }
}



override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 0) {
        supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
        return
    }

    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just override the `Activity.OnBackPressed()` method in a BaseActivity which every of your activities will inherit.
In that function, just check if the current Activity is of type `A`. If yes, exit the app, otherwise, launch Activity A.

Comment: Is just one activity actually

Comment: So, just do it ont this activity by checking the current displayed fragment or the current selected item in the BottomNavigationView.

Answer (score 0):

Set BACK_STACK_HOME_TAG state only when adding fragment A1. No need to pop back state when adding fragment B1, C1, D1...
Override onKeyDown() in fragment A1, make it quit app:
`System.exit(0);`
Override onKeyDown() in fragment B1, C1, D1..., set it back to A1 like:
`fragmentManager().popBackStack(BACK_STACK_HOME_TAG, 0);`
For A2, B2, C2, D2..., just pop itself to go back to A1, B1, C1, D1...
`fragmentManager().popBackStack();`